# PHP Script to post and retrieve multiple select combo values from a form

Tags: php, html

I have page that lists movies.

The same movie may be listed with different resolutions and there is also a quantity selector for each one to select how many copies the user wants to buy.

Using a while loop I read from the database the available resolutions for the movie, in order to build a select combo with the corresponding quantity in stock  for each resolution and a submit button "Add to Cart"

My question is: How may I post the form using the post method and get the selected quantity?

Here is the code I am using:

```
<tr class="form-box">
<th height="50px">Quantity</th>

<?php

$QuantityDisplay=getMovieResolutions($movieSecond['MovieID']);
while($q = mysql_fetch_array($QuantityDisplay)){
$i=0;
?>
<td style=" margin-left:10px;">
             <select style="width:120px" name="quantity">
<option value="0">Select</option>

<?php

while($i <= $q['QuantityInStock']){
    ?>
<option ><?php echo $i;?></option>
    <?php  $i=$i+1; }?>
</td>
<td> <input type="submit" value="Add To Cart" name"addToCart"> </td>
 <?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Post us at least the form :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change the name of the select tags to `quantity[]`

Then you will have an array in your PHP that you can access with:

```
$_POST['quantity']
```

But there are some things you could improve in your code:

- To increase an integer (`$i=$i+1`) you can use `$i++`
- The mysql extension is deprecated. Use [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: marc for example : if I have 3 resolutions for  the given movie ... so the form will contains 3 select lists for quantity and 3 submit buttons . when I click any button the $_POST['quantity'] gets the last select list value only

Comment: Then you need either to name the selects differently or rename it to `quantity[]` and the $_POST['quantity'] will be an array

Comment: ok but still I have a problem : how to know this quantity for which resolution ? since I have more than one quantity select list and more than one resolution

Comment: create a hidden inputfield `resolution[]` for every resolution. Then you will have as much elements in `$_POST['resolution']` as in `$_POST['quantity']` so you can loop over them with `foreach($_POST['resolution'] as $key => $resolution)` and access the quantity with `$_POST['quantity'][$key]`

Answer (score 1):

All your selects are named `quantity`, so you have a problem with overlapping ids.

Give each select a different name, for example:

```
<select style="width:120px" name="quantity<?php echo $i; ?>">
```

Then you'll be able to retrieve the quantities as:

```
$quantities = array();
$i=0;
while (isset($_POST['quantity'.$i])) {
  $quantities[] = $_POST['quantity'.$i];
  $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all make different name for your select box if you are using it in loop .otherwise you will get the first selected item in the `$_POST` if there will more than one value something like

```
<tr class="form-box">
<th height="50px">Quantity</th>

<?php

$QuantityDisplay=getMovieResolutions($movieSecond['MovieID']);
$j=1;
while($q = mysql_fetch_array($QuantityDisplay)){
$i=0;
?>
<td style=" margin-left:10px;">
             <select style="width:120px" name="quantity<? echo $j; ?>">
<option value="0">Select</option>

<?php

while($i <= $q['QuantityInStock']){
    ?>
<option ><?php echo $i;?></option>
    <?php  $i=$i+1; }?>
</td>
<td> <input type="submit" value="Add To Cart" name"addToCart"> </td>
 <?php
$j++;
}
```

?>